# Is there a hard limit on socket.io connections?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

### Background

We have a server that has `socket.io` 2.0.4. This server receives petitions from a stress script that simulates clients using `socket.io-client` 2.0.4.

The scrip simulates the creation of clients ( each client with its own socket ) that sends a petition and immediately dies after, using `socket.disconnect()`;

### Problem

During the first few of seconds all goes well. But every test reaches a point in which the script starts spitting out the following error:

> connect_error: Error: websocket error

This means that the clients my script is creating are not connecting to the server because they are unable to connect.

This script creates 7 clients per second ( spaced evenly throughout the second ), each client makes 1 petition and then dies.

### Research

At first I thought there was an issue with file descriptors and limits imposed by UNIX, since the server is in a Debian machine:

- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1393

After following these suggestions, the issue remained however.

Then I though maybe my test script was not connecting correctly, so I changed the connection options as in this discussion:

- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1097

Still, to no avail.

### What could be wrong?

I see the machine's CPU's are constantly at 100% so I guess I am pounding the server with requests. 
But if I am not mistaken, the server should simply accept more requests and process them when possible.

### Questions

- Is there a limit to the amount of connections a socket.io server can handle?

Comment: If the application is so busy that it cannot collect new connections from the OS, the server port's connection backlog queue in the kernel will eventually fill up with accepted but not-yet-collected connections.  When that queue is full, further connection attempts from clients will be ignored and the clients will eventually see connection failures. If this is happening then `netstat -tn` on the client should show a bunch of connections in the SYN_SENT state.

Comment: Excellent comment. One of the issues we were getting was similar, SYN_FLOOD. The operative system thought we were somehow DDOSed and so it stopped receiving connections. We fixed this issue later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When making such stress tests one needs to be aware of protections and gate keepers.

In our case, our stack was deployed in AWS. So first, the AWS load balancers started blocking us because they thought the system was being DDOSed.

Then, the Debian system was getting flooded and it started refusing connections with SYN_FLOOD.

But after fixing that we were still having the error. Turns out we had to increase TCP connection's buffer and how TCP connections were being handled in the kernel.

Now it accepts all connections, but I wish no one the suffering we went through to find it out...

Comment: Sorry for late comment. How did you set up your server environment to solve the problem? We have a similar problem.

Comment: We had a DevOps expert that changed the limits on the OS Kernel. If you guys have a DevOps, this is likely a task for him.